# why the provided time text changes in cucumber java?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, parameterized

I am using Seleninun+Java+Cucumber+Junit in my project. There is a feature that i need to automate it. It is about time setting. There is a time input box. User can type the time by manually in this format: "22:00 pm". I used one parameterize step in my feature file. I send the time as String. But while it was written, the text is changing like that "am :0022". And also this format is not stabil. it changes every time. That's why i am not able to assert the time. I don't know how can i handle tis issue?

I tried to use String manipulation but it did not work

This is my scenario
`Then click and clear event start hour and type manually "22:00 am"`

This is my code

```
Actions actions = new Actions(Driver.getDriver());

actions.clickAndHold(eventPage.startTime).moveToElement(eventPage.startDate).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).perform();

actions.sendKeys(hour).perform();
}


This is html code:

<input id="feed_cal_event_from_timecal_3Jcl" name="TIME_FROM_" type="text" value="" size="6" title="Select start date and time" autocomplete="off">

<script>
        function bxLoadClock_feed_cal_event_from_timecal_3Jcl(callback)
        {
                        if (!window.JCClock && !window.jsUtils)
            {
                return setTimeout(function(){bxLoadClock_feed_cal_event_from_timecal_3Jcl(callback);}, 50);
            }

            if (!window.JCClock)
            {
                if(!!window.bClockLoading)
                {
                    return setTimeout(function(){bxLoadClock_feed_cal_event_from_timecal_3Jcl(callback);}, 50);
                }
                else
                {
                    window.bClockLoading = true;
                    return BX.load(
                        [
                            '/bitrix/js/main/clock.js?154877654922135',
                            '/bitrix/themes/.default/clock.css?15487765656522'
                        ],
                        function() {bxLoadClock_feed_cal_event_from_timecal_3Jcl(callback)}
                    );
                }
            }

            window.bClockLoading = false;

            var obId = 'bxClock_feed_cal_event_from_timecal_3Jcl';

            window[obId] = new JCClock({
                step: 5,
                initTime: '',
                showIcon: false,
                inputId: 'feed_cal_event_from_timecal_3Jcl',
                iconId: 'feed_cal_event_from_timecal_3Jcl_icon',
                zIndex: 0,
                AmPmMode: false,
                MESS: {
                    Insert: 'Set Time',
                    Close: 'Close',
                    Hours: 'Hours',
                    Minutes: 'Minutes',
                    Up: 'Increase (Up)',
                    Down: 'Decrease (Down)'
                }
                });

            return callback.apply(window, [window[obId]]);
        }

        function bxShowClock_feed_cal_event_from_timecal_3Jcl(id)
        {
            bxLoadClock_feed_cal_event_from_timecal_3Jcl(function(obClock)
            {
                obClock.Show(id);
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Provide the html structure so we can have more context. Inspect the page and copy the html structure.